# How do I create linked X entities for a X entity using Entity Framework Core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want create a **Product** entity and that entity can have list of Products as **LinkedProducts** but I don't know why my codes not working. I'm student and very newbie to EF core mapping. 

I created 2 Entity Classes Product.cs and ProductLink.cs, here is my classes

**Product.cs**

```
    public class Product : Content
    {
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual Guid? ThumbnailImageId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ThumbnailImageId")]
        public virtual Media ThumbnailImage { get; set; }

        public virtual List<ProductLink> ProductLinks { get; set; } = new List<ProductLink>();
    }
```

**ProductLink.cs**

```
    public class ProductLink : EntityBase
    {
        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

        public virtual Guid? ProductId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LinkedProductId")]
        public virtual Product LinkedProduct { get; set; }

        public virtual Guid? LinkedProductId { get; set; }
    }
```

Error :

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Product.ProductLinks' of type 'List'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *two* relationships through `ProductLink.Product` and `ProductLink.LinkedProduct` reference navigation properties, but only *one* collection navigation property `Product.ProductLinks`, so EF does not know how to map them.

The minimum change required is to map the `ProductLinks` to one of the two related properties, for instance using `InverseProperty` attribute:

```
[InverseProperty("Product")]
public virtual List<ProductLink> ProductLinks { get; set; } = new List<ProductLink>();
```

For more info, see [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) documentation topic.

Answer (score 0):

So a bit more information on what exactly you're trying to do here would be helpful. From what I can see though, everything can probably be consolidated into a single Product class like so.

```
    public class Product : Content
    {
        public virtual string NormalizedName { get; set; }

        public virtual string ShortDescription { get; set; }

        public virtual string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual Guid? ThumbnailImageId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ThumbnailImageId")]
        public virtual Media ThumbnailImage { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public virtual Guid? ProductId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LinkId")]
        public virtual Guid? LinkId { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Product> ProductLinks { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
    }
```

What error are you receiving exactly?

Comment: I added error summary, `public virtual Guid? LinkId { get; set; }` I want trying Many-to-Many why I need `linkId` ?

Comment: You shouldn't be carrying on a discussion in an Answer. If you have questions they need to be posted in a Comment.